# How to stop my Android app with a warning when the user has USB Connected the storage to the PC

Tags: android

My app needs some files from the user's phone USB storage or the SD card and when they have the mass storage connected to the PC for file transfer, my app crashes.

I want to check whether the usb is connected in file transfer mode and if it is, to stop my app and display a Toast with a warning, the same way that the native camera app does.

I read a lot on the subject and there are various solutions, all of them semi-working

```
public static boolean isUSBConnected(Context context) {
    Intent usbCheck = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE"));
    return usbCheck.getExtras().getBoolean("connected");
}

    if (isUSBConnected(this)) {
        toastMaker.toast(MainActivity.this, "Warning message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        finish();
    }
```

but it works even if the USB cable is plugged in the device without the file transfer mode on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you can try with this, to check if the storage is available and/or writable,

```
private static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() {  
  String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();  
  if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState)) {  
   return true;  
  }  
  return false;  
 }  

 private static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {  
  String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();  
  if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) {  
   return true;  
  }  
  return false;  
 }
```

Also you should try/catch all read/write operations, you have all examples here:
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/android-internal-external-storage.html

Comment: What permission should I add to the manifest in order to check the storage state?

Comment: I'm not sure now (and not able to check it from my mobile), i think that none, but probably  READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Anyways if you plan to read, you already need it, and if you plan to write, you need  WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE that already grants read permissions

Answer (score 0):

The broadcast receiver somehow gets swallowed by the system, so I couldn't pick it up by using the internal broadcast monitor (that I installed from Google Play).

The only real solution is to see what error gets triggered by the files not being found and then **catching** that io error to make sure it gets handled properly.